# Remote GNU Parallel job gets "/bin/bash: Permission denied"

Tags: gnu-parallel

Having a problem where running a GNU Parallel job in distributed mode (ie. across multiple machines via the `--sshloginfile`) and finding that even though the job is running on each machine as the same user (or at least dictated that way in the file being given to the `--sshloginfile` (eg. myuser@myhostname00x)), getting a "Permission denied" error when the job tries to access a file. This occurs despite being able to (passwordless) ssh into the remote nodes in question and `ls` the files that the Parallel job claims it has no permissions for (the specified path is to a filesystem that is shared and NFS mounted on all the nodes).

Have a list file of nodes like

```
me@host001
me@host005
me@host006
```

and the actual Parallel job looks like

```
bcpexport() {
    <do stuff to arg $1 to BCP copy to a MSSQL DB>
}
export -f bcpexport
parallel -q -j 10 --sshloginfile $basedir/src/parallel-nodes.txt --env $bcpexport \
    bcpexport {} "$TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN" $DB $TABLE $USER $PASSWORD $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE $DELIMITER \
    ::: $DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB
```

where the `$DATAFILES/$TARGET_GLOB` glob pattern returns files from a directory. Running this job in single node mode works fine, but when running across all the nodes in the parallel-nodes.txt file throws

> /bin/bash: line 27: /path/to/file001: Permission denied
>
> /bin/bash: line 27: /path/to/file002: Permission denied
>
> ...and so on for all the files...

If anyone knows what could be going on here, advice or debugging suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the additional $:

```
parallel [...] --env $bcpexport bcpexport {} [...]
```

Unless you set the shell variable `$bcpexport` to something you probably meant `bcpexport` (no $) instead.

If `$bcpexport` is undefined, then it will be replace with nothing by the shell. Thus `--env` will eat the next argument, so you will really be running:

```
parallel [...] --env bcpexport {} [...]
```

which will execute `{}` as a command, which is exactly what you experience.

So try this instead:

```
parallel [...] --env bcpexport bcpexport {} [...]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you a bit though about what is going on with parallels when using `--env bcpexport` vs `--env $bcpexport`?

Comment: `$name` is a shell variable. `name` is a string. If you do not set `$name` it will be empty and thus be replaced by the shell with nothing, whereas `name` will evaluate to `name`. So this really has nothing to do with GNU Parallel and everything to do with the difference in shell between `$foo` and `foo`.